# Cocoapods library doesn't correctly return isKindOfClass during unit tests

Tags: ios, unit-testing, cocoapods, ecslidingviewcontroller

I have a library that I installed with Cocoapods (ECSlidingViewController). In the code, a comparison is done using -isKindOfClass. In the debugger, printing descriptions and everything says this variable is an ECSlidingViewController. However, when the code is running, it returns NO.

Currently I have my podfile linking the libraries with both the main target and the test target. If I don't do this, the test target can't find the libraries.

Comment: There are conditions where you can have two copies of the same class.  Don't recall many details, though.

Comment: Ok. Any suggestions on how to fix it, or what else to do?

Comment: Well, you can fetch the class name, and compare that.  The other thing to do is to somehow arrange for the test to be done in the pod where the object is being created.

Answer (score 1):

This answer solved it for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/27165120/2777364.

In short you should not link pod with your test target and you should create separate linking with at least one other pod for test target to force generating configuration set.

```
target 'MainTarget' do
    pod 'PodYouTryToTest'
end

target 'Tests' do
    pod 'AtLeastOneOtherPod'
end
```

Answer above is "The Right Way" of solving this. As a quick workaround I can propose a method:

```
Class getBundleDependentClass(Class class) { 
     return NSClassFromString(NSStringFromClass(class)); 
}
```

Comment: this solved the issue for me. My podfile is:

target 'Rentalia-iOS', :exclusive => true do
        pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.24.0' 
end

target 'Rentalia-iOSTests', :exclusive => true do
        pod 'OCMockito', '~> 1.0'
end