# iOS project builds ok, but when built for test complains for missing cocoa pods lib?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, xctest

I have a project using cocoa pods,
all is woking fine,

but now that i did cmd+u, for testing the app,

i get an error on my app-prefix.pch

complaining that
 CoreData+MagicalRecord.h file not found

but only complains for trying to test, builds fine...

this is a lib from a cocoapods,

what am i missing?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Libraries not found when using CocoaPods with iOS logic tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512792/libraries-not-found-when-using-cocoapods-with-ios-logic-tests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17885961/902968) is what you want:

What you want to use is [`link_with`](http://docs.cocoapods.org/podfile.html#link_with) from your `Podfile`. Something like:

```
link_with 'MainTarget', 'MainTargetTests'
```

Then run `pod install` again.

The bigger issue is probably that your unit test target isn't dependent on your main target. If you fixed that more like the Xcode template projects you'd be better off in the long run.