# isKindOfClass doesn't match across targets when using a pod

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, build-process

I'm having issues unit testing code involving an `isKindOfClass` check. There are a lot of existing question on this topic and the answers recommend:

- Make sure `-ObjC` is included as an "other linker flag". It is.
- Make sure the `.m` files from the project target are not added to the test target. They aren't.
- ...?

To make sure there weren't odd circumstances, I created a fresh project. I:

- Created an "Empty Application" project
- Added a PodFile referencing `"TwistedOakCollapsingFutures"`
- Ran `pod install`
- Opened the workspace
- Verified `-ObjC` is present in both targets
- Added a method returning `[TOCFuture futureWithResult:@1]` to `AppDelegate.m`
- Added `XCTAssert([AppDelegate.makeFuture isKindOfClass:TOCFuture.class], @"")` to the example test
- Ran the unit tests (the assert failed)

Basically I have no idea why this shouldn't work. Even more oddly, if I go *counter* to existing answers and include `AppDelegate.m` in the test target, the test starts to pass.

What is going on? Am I suppose to include the source files in the test target, or am I not supposed to?

Comment: It has been seen before that, with multiple static libs included in an app, you can get more than one instance of the class object for a given class.

Comment: (I believe what you need to do is to somehow reference the class in the "main" code, before either static lib references it.)

Answer (score 2):

This answer solved it for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/27165120/2777364.

In short you should not link pod with your test target and you should create separate linking with at least one other pod for test target to force generating configuration set.

```
target 'MainTarget' do
    pod 'PodYouTryToTest'
end

target 'Tests' do
    pod 'AtLeastOneOtherPod'
end
```

Answer above is "The Right Way" of solving this. As a quick workaround I can propose a method:

```
Class getBundleDependentClass(Class class) { 
     return NSClassFromString(NSStringFromClass(class)); 
}
```

Comment: What do you do with that method? Do you use it as a category? What does that look like in objc??